# How do I do some basic js exporting using Webpack 3

Tags: webpack

I have sample script as follows:

```
var o = o || {};

o.showMsg = function () {
    console.log("something else");
}

o.showMsg();
```

I built/bundled above script using webpack and it works as expected.  When bundled using webpack, the above script encapsulated as part of IIFE (by design) and is fine.  However, I would like to access the object "o" in the host page (where I would include my bundle.js).  Is there any other way, I can export and give access of "o" externally to other scripts.  I thought of adding "window.o = o" to above script.  Not sure, if it is best/recommended way (or there are other, in fact, better ways to achieve the same).

Also, imagine I would like to export a couple of constructor functions to external scripts for which they would instantiate on their own.  How would I export those constructor functions externally using webpack.

NOTE: As I am learning some basics of webpack here, I would not want to go with ES6/ES7/TS for now.  I understand that they have lot more functionality than what I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose in your webpack config how you expose your library with [libraryTarget](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget).

You can export your library in an ES6 way with `import`/`export` and let webpack do the job.